# Proving that a set is closed under derivability

Tags: logic

Let $v:At \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be fixed and consider the set $\gamma=\{\phi:v[\phi]=1\}$. I am trying to prove that this set is closed under derivability. I have begun by assuming that $\phi$ is derivable from $\gamma$, but that it is not in $\gamma$. This means that $v[\phi]=0$, $v[\neg \phi]=1$, and so $\neg \phi \in \gamma$. From this point, however, I am not sure how to derive a contradiction.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you say more about the notions you're working with? What definition of "derivability" are you using?

Comment: There is no need for a proof by contradiction. Instead, prove by induction on the length of derivations that whenever $\phi$ is derivable from $\gamma$, then $v[\phi]=1$.